# Time series plot ggplot

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, dplyr

hi I don't know what is wrong with the season plot

```
forecast::ggseasonplot(x = as.ts(update))+
ggtitle("sales")+
  ylab("time")
```

[image: the image doesn't seem to be the right one]

Comment: You probably exchanged a date variable with a factor variable at some point.

Comment: no it was not a date and I converted it to a date